# Angular 17 + Bootstrap 5.3.2 (popper.js not working) trying to migrate to @floating-ui (rebranded popper.js)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, popper.js, floating-ui

I'm using Angular 17 to build a web app and I'm trying to use Bootstrap as I've always done.
Every time I've used Bootstrap I've included it with CDN links and now I'm trying to include it via npm and I've installed it with `npm install bootstrap` as the offical website suggest and I've seen  everywhere that Bootstrap is based on third party library like popper.js and so on.

The main problem is that some of the Bootstrap functionalities like dropdowns, accordions and more are broken with popper.js that seems to be deprecated now.

So I'm including Bootstrap via npm and also including it inside my `angular.json` like this:

[image]

Inside the list of scripts, from the first to the fourth basically I'm trying to specify the path to the new rebranded popper.js library (called @floating-ui) and this fix my problems on the web app (dropdowns and accordions stopped working) but I receive an error on the console:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it and I've tried to rearrange the imports but didn't worked. That's the structure of the library installed:

[image]

I've installed @floating-ui via npm with `npm install @floating-ui/dom`.

If anyone can help me I would be grateful,
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap I recommend to check [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

"Angular widgets built from the ground up using Bootstrap 5 CSS with APIs designed for the Angular ecosystem"

Comment: Do not post pictures of text.

Comment: @robert Thank you for the answer, I've installed ng-bootstrap and it made me discover that some of my angular/cli packages were out to date and adding this package also installed bootstrap and popperjs/core so when I figured that probably this package was not what I needed it actually solved the problem and I'm leaving everything like this.